# Expand a column of lists into multiple rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe where one of the columns is a list. I'd like to expand this list.

How can I do this?

**Begin with:**

```
0 [{ first: 'jon', last: 'McSmith' }, { first: 'Jennifer', last: 'Foobar'}]
1 [{ first: 'dan', last: 'Raizman' }, { first: 'Alden', last: 'Lowe'}]

Name: players, dtype: object
```

**End with:**

```
   first         last
--------------------------
0  Jon           McSmith
1  Jennifer      Foobar
2  Dan           Raizman
3  Alden         Lowe
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to stack the lists in column `players` horizontally and create a new dataframe :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(df['players']).tolist())
```

Or use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) (available in pandas version >= `0.25`),

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['players'].explode().tolist())
```

Another option using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as suggested by @cs95

```
from itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df['players']))
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

      first     last
0       jon  McSmith
1  Jennifer   Foobar
2       dan  Raizman
3     Alden     Lowe
```

Comment: Thanks @shubham when I try this I get back an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @DonP Is the first method working fine? Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you that seems to work (I don't know who is downvoting by the way). Can you explain what is happening and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: Not me, this is a good answer. Many ways to skin a cat but stack or concatenate is the fastest way to chain the sublists. Another option is itertools.chain.

Comment: Good answer +1, but i tried to reproduce it for my understanding, any clue why it doesnt words `df = pd.DataFrame({"listi": ["[{ first: 'jon', last: 'McSmith' }, { first: 'Jennifer', last: 'Foobar'}]" , "[{ first: 'dan', last: 'Raizman' }, { first: 'Alden', last: 'Lowe'}]"]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['listi'].explode().tolist())
print(df1)`

Comment: @A.B Thanks, you are creating dataframe from strings thats why its not working, remove the quotation marks around the lists and this will work fine.